# On Lefschetz theorem and sum of Betti numbers as lower bounds for fixed points

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, fixed-point-theorems, euler-characteristics

Let $M$ be a closed manifold with holomorphic cell decomposition (if it is complex), or at least with only even cohomology. In particular, its Euler characteristic is equal to the sum of its Betti number.

Let $\phi$ be a diffeomorphism which is isotopic to the identity. As far a I understand, Lefschetz theorem implies that $\phi$ must have at least one fixed point. Moreover, its Lefschetz number is equal to the sum of Betti numbers of $M$.

Is it straightforward then that the number of fixed points of $\phi$, counted with multiplicity, is at least the sum of Betti numbers ? I guess my problem lies in the fact that I don't really know how to relate the Lefschetz number and the multiplicity of the fixed points.

Comment: The Lefschetz number is not the sum of Betti numbers. It is the Euler characteristic, i.e., the alternating sum of Betti numbers.

Comment: @ThiKu: yes, but the assumption is that $M$ has a decomposition by even-dimensional cells, so there are no odd degree Betti numbers.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I think that my problem actually lies in the fact that I don't really understand the relation between the Lefschetz number of $\phi$ and the total multiplicity of its fixed points.

Comment: What is the definition of a holomorphic cell decomposition?

Comment: It is a cellular decomposition into holomorphic cells. It means in particular that the cohomology is concentrated in even degrees. My statement about Betti sum and Euler characteristic holds as soon as there is no odd degree cohomology. You're right, I should assume that the manifold is complex at least.

Comment: The quantity that more naturally relates with the number of fixed points is the Nielsen number. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nielsen_theory

Comment: Thanks. Still, it would be nice to know if the sum of the fixed points counted with multiplicity is always greater than the Lefschetz number ? From what I understand, the fixed-point index can be negative, so should I understand it as the multiplicity with some sign ?

Comment: The only notion of multiplicity I know for fixed points is the fixed point index. The sum of the fixed points counted with their fixed point index EQUALS the Lefschetz number, whenever the set of fixed points is finite. That's the Lefschetz trace formula.